# pydantic root validation get inconsistent data

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, pydantic

I write some project on FastAPI + ormar, and there is a problem with PATCH method of my API endpoint. Briafly (without try-excepts and checks for ids), my PATCH logic is the following:

```py
new_product_values = new_product.dict(
    exclude_unset=True,
    exclude_none=True,
)
db_product = await Product.objects.get_or_none(pk=product_id)
product = await db_product.update(**new_product_values)  # update cause validation and inside it cause ValidationError
```

`product_id` is query_parameter and `new_product` is pydantic model (optional version of my ormar model) from request body.

So, Product model has the following validator, in which ValidationError is raised in my case:

```py
@validator("fat", "protein", "carbohyd")
@classmethod
def nutrients_min_value(cls, value: float) -> float:
    """Check nutrient 0 < value < product_base_weight.

    Args:
        value (float): nutrient (fat, protein or carbohyd) of product.

    Returns:
        float: nutrient (fat, protein or carbohyd) of product.
    """
    assert (
        0 <= value <= PRODUCT_BASE_WEIGHT
    ), f"Nutrient amount must be in range [0...{PRODUCT_BASE_WEIGHT}]"
    return value

@root_validator
@classmethod
def nutrient_sum_constraint(cls, values: dict[str, int | str | float | bool]):
    """Validate nutrient sum.

    Args:
        values (dict): Product as dict.

    Returns:
        dict: Product as dict.
    """
    fat: float = values.get("fat")  # type: ignore
    protein: float = values.get("protein")  # type: ignore
    carbohyd: float = values.get("carbohyd")  # type: ignore
    assert (
        0 <= fat + protein + carbohyd <= PRODUCT_BASE_WEIGHT
    ), f"Total weight of fat, protein and carbohyd must be in range [0...{PRODUCT_BASE_WEIGHT}]"
    return values
```

This root_validator is needed to check, if sum of nutrients in product (always 100g weight) is bigger and equal than 0 and less and equal than 100. (it is impossible to have weight of nutrients bigger than product weight itself). (+ I've added one another validator, because it will be needed below).

I passed the following json in my patch endpoint: `{"fat": 26, "carbohyd": 49}` (initial values of product was the following `{"fat": 25, "carbohyd": 50, "protein": 25}`, which sum is equal to 100, and its correct), but patch request fail, because carbohyd value, when it checks in root_validator still equal to 50, but fat value is already equal to 26, and further sum will be 101, that is bigger than 100.

It means, that root_validation triggers inside pydantic model logic too early, so not all values were passed in it.

debug show me, that update method cause all model validation, but root_validation causes not after all other validations (`nutrients_min_value` for all nutrients), but right after fat validation in `nutrient_min_value`. What should I do?

Comment: Upd: removing `nutrient_min_value` validator and making asserts in root_validator didn't change anything, and root_validator still recieve incorrect values. I think, ormar is the problem, because inside `update` method, if I pass kwargs in it, it make for loop setattr, and every time make validation for each settattr. Any idea, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the problem stems from the fact that `update` calls the [`update_from_dict`](https://github.com/collerek/ormar/blob/0.12.0/ormar/models/newbasemodel.py#L872) method, which just calls `setattr` in a loop for each key-value-pair.

Whether or not this should be considered a bug depends on the goals behind the Pydantic integration. I am not particularly familiar with `ormar`. I suppose this may be worth a feature request though.

A workaround for the time being is initializing an entirely new instance of your model with the updated data and using the [`upsert`](https://collerek.github.io/ormar/models/methods/#upsert) method. This should accomplish, what you want.

Here is a full working example:

```py
from asyncio import run
from databases import Database
from ormar import Integer, Model, NoMatch
from pydantic import ValidationError, root_validator
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine


DB_URL = "sqlite:///test.db"
_db = Database(DB_URL)
_meta = MetaData()


class Foo(Model):
    class Meta:
        metadata = _meta
        database = _db
        tablename = "foo"

    id: int = Integer(primary_key=True)
    a: int = Integer(minimum=0, maximum=100)
    b: int = Integer(minimum=0, maximum=100)
    c: int = Integer(minimum=0, maximum=100)

    @root_validator
    def sum_constraint(cls, values: dict[str, int]) -> dict[str, int]:
        assert 0 <= sum((
            values["a"],
            values["b"],
            values["c"],
        )) <= 100, "Sum of `a`, `b`, and `c` must be in [0..100]"
        return values


async def patch_handler(pk: int, data: dict[str, int]) -> Foo:
    try:
        obj = await Foo.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except NoMatch:
        pass
    else:
        data = obj.dict() | data
    new_obj = Foo(**data)
    await new_obj.upsert()
    return new_obj


async def main() -> None:
    engine = create_engine(DB_URL)
    _meta.drop_all(engine)
    _meta.create_all(engine)
    await Foo.objects.create(a=25, b=50, c=25)
    data = {"a": 26, "b": 49}
    new_obj = await patch_handler(1, data)
    print(new_obj)
    data = {"a": 27}
    try:
        await patch_handler(1, data)
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

The output:

```
id=1 a=26 b=49 c=25
1 validation error for Foo
__root__
  Sum of `a`, `b`, and `c` must be in [0..100] (type=assertion_error)
```

A few more things to note:

- The `classmethod` decorator is redundant, when you are using Pydantic `validator` or `root_validator` decorators.
- Unless there are other things you are doing with that first field `validator` in your example, you may be better off simply using the built-in `maximum` and `minimum` parameters for the [`Integer`](https://collerek.github.io/ormar/fields/field-types/#integer) field class. Also that docstring description is not congruent with your assertion since you write about `<`, but actually use `<=`.
- The order of [dictionary merging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (via `|`) inside the `patch_handler` function is important because `data = obj.dict() | data` ensures that the values passed via `data` overwrite what is returned by the `dict` method from the existing object. This is why we cannot just do `data |= obj.dict()`.
- Instead of using that `try`-`except`-`else`-construct, you can also use the [`get_or_none`](https://collerek.github.io/ormar/queries/read/#get_or_none) method as before and then do an `if ... is None`-check or something to that effect. Matter of personal preference.